# Get longest streak from list

Tags: java, list

In Java I am writing code to analyze the longest streak of a color from the output of another program. The program can output three colors: Red, green, and black. Green counts as whichever color is being checked (e.g. RRGR = Red x4). The current code I am using is:

```
private static boolean isStreak(int color, int... lst){
    for(int i:lst){
        if(i!=color){//Whichever color is being checked
            if(i!=-12280508)//Green counts as whichever color is being checked
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

While this code works, I need several if/else blocks to effectively catch all the streaks from 1-7, such as:

```
if(isStreak(Color.RED.value,last[lSize-1],last[lSize-2],last[lSize-3],last[lSize-4],last[lSize-5],last[lSize-6],last[lSize-7])){
    if(!lb.was7){
        log("red 7x");
        doBet(bet*64);
        betBlack();
        lb.was7=true;
    }
}else if(isStreak(Color.BLACK.value,last[lSize-1],last[lSize-2],last[lSize-3],last[lSize-4],last[lSize-5],last[lSize-6],last[lSize-7])){
    if(!lb.was7){
        log("red 7x");
        doBet(bet*64);
        betRed();
        lb.was7=true;
    }
}else if(isStreak(Color.RED.value,last[lSize-1],last[lSize-2],last[lSize-3],last[lSize-4],last[lSize-5],last[lSize-6])){
    log("red 6x");
    doBet(bet*32);
    betBlack();
}else if(isStreak(Color.BLACK.value,last[lSize-1],last[lSize-2],last[lSize-3],last[lSize-4],last[lSize-5],last[lSize-6])){
    log("black 6x");
    doBet(bet*32);
    betRed();
}
```

and so on. I was wondering if there was a way to write some code that would take the arguments of a list like:

```
getStreak(int[] list)
```

and would return the length of the streak and the color of the streak. I have no idea where to go or where to start, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a subtle edge case with this problem.  It might be easier to solve it in two passes of the array.   If you have a sequence of `RRRRGBBBB` I assume that there's two possible "streaks".  Either it's a sequence of 5 REDS or it can be considered a sequence of 5 BLACKS.

Comment: @selbie It would look for the most recent streak, closest to list[list.length]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to store the color of the current streak that you are on and the length of that streak. Loop through the colors in the list, and for each one, if it is the same as the color of the current streak or it is green, increment the current streak counter. Once the streak ends, check if it is longer than the longest previous streak (which you must keep track of). If so, update the longest streak and its color, reset the current streak, and continue looking for a longer streak.

Here is some code that you could put into a `getStreak(int[] colors)` method to accomplish this:

```
if (colors != null && colors.length > 0) {
    // Default streaks to 1, and colors to the first color
    int longestStreak = 1;
    int longestStreakColor = colors[0];
    int currStreak = 1;
    int currStreakColor = colors[0];

    // Start at index 1 since we already stored the first color in currStreakColor
    for (int i = 1; i < colors.length; i++) {
        // If the color is the same as the previous color or is green,
        // increment the currStreak
        if (colors[i] == currStreakColor || colors[i] == Color.GREEN.value) {
            currStreak++;
        } else {
            // If the color is different and the streak that just ended was
            // longer than the previous longest streak, update longestStreak
            // and longestStreakColor
            if (currStreak > longestStreak) {
                longestStreak = currStreak;
                longestStreakColor = currStreakColor;
            }
            // Reset currStreak
            currStreak = 1;
        }
        // Set currStreakColor to the current color if it isn't green
        if (colors[i] != Color.GREEN.value) {
            currStreakColor = colors[i];
        }
    }
}

// If we ended on a streak longer than the previous longest streak, update
// longestStreak and longestStreakColor
if (currStreak > longestStreak) {
    longestStreak = currStreak;
    longestStreakColor = currStreakColor;
}
```

If you want this code in a method, to return the color and the streak you may have to create a class, such as `ColorStreak`, that has two `int` fields, one for the color and one for the length of the streak. Then, create a new `ColorStreak` from `longestStreak` and `longestStreakColor` and return it (since a function can only return one value).